# Как работает этa function?

Tags: javascript, функции

У меня есть вот такой код:

```js
function showMessage(from, text) {
  from = '*' + from + '*';
  console.log(from);
}

let from = 10;
showMessage(from); //--> *10*
console.log(from);
```

Я читаю [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/function-basics) это:

> ...переданные значения копируются в локальные переменные... Затем они используются в теле функции.

Вопрос: неужели значение аргумента может быть перезаписано внешней одноименной переменной? Получается, что локальная переменная получает значение глобальной?

Также непонятны такие слова по поводу этого отрезка кода на том же сайте:

> Обратите внимание: функция изменяет значение from, но это изменение не видно снаружи. Функция всегда получает только копию значения.

О какой копии идёт речь?

Comment: Так вы же сами передали ее как параметр (。_。)

Comment: Вы передали from (10) в функцию showMessage, там эта from буде скопирована и будет новая 10. Потом вы поменяли from, но поменяли ту, которая была скопирована. Но если бы мы передавали массив либо объект, то там значение не копировалось бы.

Comment: @entithat разве можно в скобки при вызове функции писать любую переменную? Как-то казалось до этого, что только значение параметров)))

Comment: не понял вопрос. Что вы имеете в виду под "писать значения параметров при вызове функции"?

Comment: @entithat я имею ввиду, что в скобках при вызове функции (то есть - showMessage(from) --> сейчас в скобках находится переменная from) можно писать не только значения для параметров, а и сами переменные. Вот это меня сбивало с толку

Comment: Ну так а как иначе? Смысл тогда с функции, если она статичные значения принимает?))

Comment: @entithat а что вы подразумеваете под "копированием" значения? Не совсем понимаю

Comment: Есть какая-то переменная со значением 10. Внутри этой функции, когда вы передали ее она скопировалась. Считайте что у вас теперь два значения 10 в памяти где-то

Comment: @entithat а, понятно. Вне и внутри этой функции. Спасибо))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Вопрос: неужели значение аргумента может быть перезаписано внешней одноименной переменной? Получается, что локальная переменная получает значение глобальной?

```
function showMessage(from, text) {
  from = '*' + from + '*';
  console.log(from);
}
```

При выполнении этого кода создается функция, которая пока находится где-то в памяти компьютера. Никаких «Значений аргументов» сейчас не существует.

```
let from = 10;
```

Создается переменная `from` со значением `10`. От того, что где-то внутри функций будет переменная / параметр с таким же названием, ничего не изменится.

```
showMessage(from);
```

Здесь функция вызывается, и ровно в этот момент, параметр функции `from` получает своё значение от внешней переменной `from` — `10` (потому что он передан в виде аргумента, в оператор вызова функции `()`, а не потому что названия одинаковые). При этом, дальнейшие изменения параметра `from` внутри функции никак не влияют на значение глобальной `from`.

Одинаковые имена могут быть использованы просто для удобства. Функция будет работать и в таком виде:

```js
function showMessage(msg) {
  msg = '*' + msg + '*';
  console.log(msg);
}

let from = 10;

showMessage(from); // msg получает значение from, оно же, 10
showMessage(1000); // напрямую получает значение - число
showMessage(" - text - ");
showMessage(); // ничего не передано, значения параметров по умолчанию - undefined
```